# Django Rest Framework: router is not working

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have used `DefaultRouter()` and viewset. Here is the code

```
from rest_framework import routers
from .api import TweetViewset, OwnersTweet
from django.urls import path

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('', TweetViewset, 'tweets')
router.register('own/', OwnersTweet, 'owner')
```

And project-level `urls.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('accounts.urls')),
    path('tweet/', include('tweets.urls'))
]
```

When I send a request to `'<URL>/tweet/own/'` It returned an error `Not Found`. But `<URL>/tweet/` is working. `OwnersTweet` view also working fine. But I think there is smth wrong with URL. Can you help, please?

Comment: You should register `router.urls` (https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/6-viewsets-and-routers/#using-routers)

Comment: It worked, I used path. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the `path`. Now it is working